# when Android studio application error

Tags: android

I am new with android app development. I am facing this problem as I run my application.

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
>        Required by:
>            My:app:unspecified

Please help

Comment: add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+'` to `dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try installing the examples in the SDK Manager. The templates may possibly be included in the examples section. And check to make sure you have the latest SDK installed
Also it looks like `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15` should be added to dependencies

Otherwise, I would advise reinstalling Android Studio. I have had several issues in the past, and at one point I just decided to uninstall && reinstall, and everything has worked smoothly since then.

Comment: I have installed latest SDK. I just designing interface and run but having these errors.